# Dynamic iPhone App icons?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipod-touch

The calender app does it... How can I make an app icon change based on stored info from the iPod or iPod app settings?

EDIT:
I realized today that it is possible to access bundles via the sdk. (At least read access) If I had a graphics API (OpenGL, perhaps) then I could possibly modify the icon like that.  The operation would be:

- get icon.png from bundle.
- modify it
- resave it into the bundle.

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't use the SDK (which of course Apple isn't restricted to with the Calendar app) – you can do badges but the image is always static.

Comment: Ok. I'll be that's why (among other reasons) the calender API is nonexistent from Apple.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Just as a note, Apple's Calendar app is actually hardcoded into the system to display a view over the icon. Put it on the left of the first page and drag to SpotLight, you will notice that the text fades out differently.

Comment: Interesting observation. Wierd though.

Comment: It's due to the fact that since it is a black text view over a white background, it fades to white, but the icon itself fades to black since it becomes invisible. To do it correctly, they would have to not fade the calendar text.

Answer (score 2):

In answer to your edit: no, you cannot alter any files inside your bundle; your application is sandboxed to only have write access within its documents, cache, and temporary directories.

Comment: What if the plist referenced a file inside the sandbox?

Comment: I heard of some hack that made something like that happen... the file being a symlink inside the bundle, or something like that. It was a while ago, though—there's a good chance it's been fixed by now.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible in new iOS 10.3 update(beta version) but you will have to specify each icon in the info.plist file.

```
func setAlternateIconName(_ alternateIconName: String?, 
    completionHandler: ((Error?) -> Void)? = nil)
```

[alternateIconName](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplication/2806818-setalternateiconname)

Comment: Checked documentation but still confused about how to implement it, in the sense of clear use case?

Comment: @Catarino https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-change-your-app-icon-dynamically-with-setalternateiconname