# Need changeable Icon for iOS app...!

Tags: iphone, ipad, icons

I need one help regarding application icon. I want to change upload one application with different icon everyday. If you want to verify, then you can check Calendar application of iPhone. It will change application icon everyday with date and day name..

Can you please tell me how it is possible ???

Comment: how it is possible? Be an Apple and have access to some private API

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421830/dynamic-iphone-app-icons and http://www.iphonehacks.com/2011/06/ios-5-concept-dynamic-icons.html