# Updating the App icon like Calendar app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, icons

I'm working on an app where I want the app icon to be updated every month, same way the iOS calendar app is updated everyday.

I guess if this would work it would change to another image that is stored in the app?

Is this possible to do? Been doing some googling but weren't really able to find the answer.

Comment: See So answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421830/dynamic-iphone-app-icons

Comment: Ridiculous!! This is a complete new question in context to ios 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No this is not possible, the app bundle is readonly and there for you can not change the app icon.

You will have to update the app every month the change the icon.

Answer (score 0):

As *rckoenes* stated it is not possible, and you can read more information about what are the things which can be seen/modifiable run-time for a given running app:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSRunningApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSRunningApplication/icon

*NSRunningApplication* is for modify and/or read information on running apps, and unfortunately app icon is read-only.

```
icon
Returns the icon for the receiver’s application. (read-only)

@property(readonly) NSImage *icon
```